# $ is not defined in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Suppose I have the following html:

```
<div id="test1">hi</div>
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv()">click here</a>
```

and the javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
    $("#test1").hide();
}
```

When I try it on jsfiddle, it returns:

> $ is not defined

Did I miss some setting in jsFiddle?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you add jQuery reference...

Comment: Did you select Jquery API from left nav bar?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery file in your `<head></head>` tags?

Comment: Could you share the link to the fiddle?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question, and voting for it to be closed? It's a perfectly good question, and may serve to help someone else who experiences exactly the same issue. Thank you for your question, @Kintaro.

Comment: *"Did I miss some setting in jsFiddle?"*  You mean like the one at the top that lists the libraries?

Comment: @thesystem, don't assume what's obvious to you is obvious to others.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Settle down. A brief look at the jsFiddle settings would have solved this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add jQuery to JSfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620565/how-to-add-jquery-to-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That suggests that you have not selected one of the jQuery libraries from the left hand side of the screen.

[image: JSFiddle]

Comment: I took a screenshot while writing my answer, but you answered first and I thought I might as well put it somewhere. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @James, I was busy making a [screenshot of my own](http://i.imgur.com/MgFkA1T.png?1) only to come back and find that you'd added one for me :)

Comment: Ha. Feel free to replace it if you prefer yours to mine... :-)

Comment: Nope. Yours is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Update for 2015: This option is now in the top right corner of the JAVASCRIPT area. I tried to add an image, but rejected by stupid, stupid reviewers.

Answer (score 10):

These answers are old and for anyone looking for an updated version the dropdown menu is now located on the gear next to the word Javascript at the top right of your javascript window in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Screenshot of the current (Dec 2015) version of jsfiddle:

[image]

I just wasted a lot of time on this silly error as well - frameworks and extensions are now selected via the "JAVASCRIPT *" button in the JavaScript pane!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is reading this in 2017, then make sure to add the jQuery [link](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js) using **https** protocol. This is to be added in the External resources tab present at the left of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Either do what @Drew and @James show.

if you remain having problems (which I know I did the other day), you can add an external resource from a CDN library

"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"

good luck !

Answer (score -1):

`$("#test1").hide();`

the above is not defined meaning the $

Example.

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#test1").hide();`
}
`

`jQuery(document).ready(function(IsNowDefined)  // just for explanation
IsNowDefined("#test1").hide();`