# How to add jQuery to JSfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

The interface of **JSfiddle** has changed and i can't see any option to add `jQuery`, and set it `onLoad` as it was Before..

So can someone help me how to activate it.

And thank you for help.

Comment: JSfiddle **changed its interface** so, in nowadays, **no answer is working**!

Comment: @PeterKrauss: It works exactly as described below for me.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Alternatively to [Velimir Tchatchevsky's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36620596/3760604) you can click the *Javascript Settings* button (top <strike>right</strike> left of Javascript pane).

[image]

You can select jQuery, and other extensions and frameworks, from the *Frameworks & Extensions* drop down.

Also, depending on the library selected there are also some other extensions to that library. An example below of jQuery 1.7.2, you can also include jQuery UI, jQuery Mobile etc.

[image]

---

In regards to Velimir Tchatchevsky's answer, the *External Resources* section on the left is more for importing other files / libraries that JSFiddle does not have.

For example, you could import libraries like FontAwesome or Datatables.js, or your own hosted CSS / JS files.

Comment: As @mry shows in their answer - the settings button is now in the top left of the JS panel.

Answer (score 7):

At the left side there is an "external resources" button that you can click and fill in the url of the jquery source

Comment: Thanks so now it doesn't set it it  self

Comment: "jquery" not works, no autocomplete... please show a concrete example to illustrate...  Ah, now working fine, https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js

Answer (score 3):

Had the same question. using ImClarky's answer figured it out in updated interface. Adding steps in updated interface. hope these help someone looking for same in future

1. Click on Javascript menu in javascript pane and select jQuery from Frameworks & Extensions menu

[image]

2. Add your code using jQuery !!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of the html block:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Example:

---

```js
function code()
{
console.log('change');
console.log($('#select').val());
$('#copySelect').html($('#select').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select" onchange="code()">
<option value="Hi">Hi</option>
<option value="Bye">Bye</option>
</select>
<span id="copySelect">
Hi
</span>
```