# Change border color of input if empty on button click

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I am trying to use jquery to change the border color of an element when it is not empty. From what I've looked up everything seems right, but I still can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jessica_mather123/ez3tgnvc/1/

HTML

```
Text <input type="text">
<button>Click Me</button>
```

JQuery

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
    if($("[type='text']").val() == null){
        $(this).css("border","2px solid red");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Use `if($("[type='text']").val() == ""){}`.

Comment: You haven't included JQuery in your fiddle, plus the `$(this)` in this context means the button you've clicked, not the text field.

Comment: Sorry About that, I was working in it so it may have changed.

Comment: Mohit, that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You didn't include jQuery (see how in [How to add jQuery to JSfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620565/how-to-add-jquery-to-jsfiddle))
- `$(this)` inside on `click` refers to the button, not the input. So you'd better replace it with `$("input[type='text']")`

So, a working demo would be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ez3tgnvc/10/

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
    var input = $("input[type='text']");
    if(!input.val()){
        input.css("border","2px solid red");
    }
});
```

`if(!input.val())` is true if input variable is empty, null or undefined.

Comment: *"see a demo"* is not a proper answer. Put the code in answer itself and use demo to support answer. Questions and answers should be self contained

Comment: This was very useful! Thank you!

Comment: Since this is a question about relatively simple conditionals, I would suggest you explain `!input.val()` just to help explain it to newer readers.

Comment: That is the same as saying input.val() = false or null right?

Comment: I updated my answer taking into consideration all your comments, let me know if anything else is unclear.

Comment: @JessicaMather, please remember to always upvote the helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` method returns a array, `null` will be returned only when no match is found.

So you should change `if($("[type='text']").val() == null)` to `if($("[type='text']").val() == "")`

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/ez3tgnvc/16/)