# Can anyone tell me, why my js code is not running on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code below works on a live site but I can't get it to run on the site jsfiddle .
it shows me the error given below:

```
{
  "message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 108,
  "colno": 9
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working on jsfiddle?
I can't find the solution, anyone here who gave me the solution
The code works as you can see when it's embedded here as snippet:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
     $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
     $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
 });
```

```css
/*
Tutorial Name: Scroll To Top Then Fixed Navigation Effect With JQuery and CSS
https://stanhub.com/scroll-to-top-then-fixed-navigation-effect-with-jquery-and-css-free-download/
Description: Create a sticky navigation bar that remains fixed to the top after scroll
Author: Stan Kostadinov
Author URI: https://stanhub.com
Version: 1.0.0 - 11.01.2014
*/

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

a {text-decoration: none;}

/* This class is added on scroll */
.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 height: 70px;
 z-index: 1;
}

body {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'open-sans-bold', AvenirNext-Medium, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Navigation Settings */
nav {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background: #fff;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 24px 10px;
}

nav li a {
 color: #757575;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

section {
 height: 100vh;
}

/* Screens Settings */
#screen1 {
 background: #43b29d;
}

#screen1 p {
 padding-top: 200px;
}

#screen2 {
 background: #efc94d;
}

#screen3 {
 background: #e1793d;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {

 nav li {
  padding: 24px 4px;
 }

 nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
 }

}
```

```html
<section id="screen1">

 <p>Scroll down</p>

 <nav>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>

</section>

<section id="screen2"></section>
<section id="screen3"></section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add jQuery to JSfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620565/how-to-add-jquery-to-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check now this code is working fine. The reason why your code is not working is that you haven't added jquery to your code

```js
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
         $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
         $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
      });
     });
```

```css
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

    a {text-decoration: none;}

    /* This class is added on scroll */
    .fixed {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     height: 70px;
     z-index: 1;
    }

    body {
     color: #fff;
     font-family: 'open-sans-bold', AvenirNext-Medium, sans-serif;
     font-size: 18px;
     text-align: center;
    }

    /* Navigation Settings */
    nav {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     background: #fff;
    }

    nav li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 24px 10px;
    }

    nav li a {
     color: #757575;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    section {
     height: 100vh;
    }

    /* Screens Settings */
    #screen1 {
     background: #43b29d;
    }

    #screen1 p {
     padding-top: 200px;
    }

    #screen2 {
     background: #efc94d;
    }

    #screen3 {
     background: #e1793d;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {

     nav li {
      padding: 24px 4px;
     }

     nav li a {
      font-size: 14px;
     }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="screen1">

     <p>Scroll down</p>

     <nav>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>

    </section>

    <section id="screen2"></section>
    <section id="screen3"></section>
```

Comment: @CodeQuit if you like & satisfy with my answer please vote me up

Comment: @CodeQuit every time a person helps than you should help him back by appreciating or vote him up by pressing up arrow.

Comment: M new here! I didn't know how to use.

Comment: That's why I taught you how to do vote & also appreciate.

Comment: the jQuery is used in html field is auto removed, when i refreshed page after save.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing jQuery library on JS Fiddle.

You can check this answer to see how to add jQuery. 
[How to add jQuery to JSfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620565/how-to-add-jquery-to-jsfiddle)

Comment: but when i refreshed the page, it changed to default settings.

Comment: you need to click the "save" button and then if you will refresh the page it will preserve your external library.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle allows you to add external JavaScript libraries/frameworks using a menu (click the little gear icon next to 'JavaScript'). The reason you're seeing that error is because `$` is (usually) defined by JQuery, and you haven't included JQuery using the JSFiddle options.

Comment: but when i refreshed the page, it changed to default settings.