# Datatables Pagination Does Not Show

Tags: python, jquery, django, datatable, datatables

What I'm trying to do is set up a table just like this:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Copied the code but then no success. I've tried so many different variables and removing all but the necessary code and I'm at a loss for what the issue may be.

I've gone through several other similar SOF questions and some mentioned "sDom" could be the case so I tried a few variations I've found online but no luck yet.

Current JS Fiddle attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/nf50j3cm/#&togetherjs=FjamrJizOe

table.html

```
{% extends "dashboard/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}

{% block styles %}


<script type="text/javascript" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">



{% endblock styles %}




<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h2 class="text-gray-800">{% block title %}{% trans "Imported Entries" %}{% endblock %}</h2>
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'import' %}"><i
            class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Import New Entires</a>
</div>

<!-- Content Row -->
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>


    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sDom": '<"support-table-header">',
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[3, 5, 10, 25, -1], [3, 5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 3,
    } );
} );

</script>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I can't comment on the rest of your set-up, but `"sDom": '<"support-table-header">'` will cause various controls to be hidden - including the pagination control. You can see why by looking at the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) documentation (where `dom` is the new name, and `sDom` is an old name only retained for backwards compatibility). Suggestion: remove that line from your DataTable configuration. Or use something like `dom: 'lfrtip'`, which is the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @andrewjames, I just let that to show one of the things I've tried. For now, I've updated it to your suggestion but still a no go. Not sure why it's not showing anything. So far it's set up exactly like the example on their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example online that I copied that finally worked. Here is a [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S7OFBY9atM) that shows the example and has github repo to copy the code.

Below is the code from the github repo and the key part for me was wrapping the js code in the child template and then calling the code again via the same block in the base.html

This took me so long to figure out as I did not know the scripts were not being called. Feel free to leave a comment below to let me know the best way to figure out if a library script is being called.

```
{% block js %}

{% endblock js %}
```

and then also calling that in

base.html

```
...

<footer>
      <p><h6> This site is brought to you by Python, Django and the YogiCoder</h6></p>
 <h6> <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:imtheyogicoder@gmail.com">imtheyogicoder@gmail.com</a></p></h6>

</footer>
      </div>

{% block js %}

{% endblock js %}



</body>
</html>
```

child.html

```
 ....

 {% block js %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.0/b-1.5.2/b-colvis-1.5.2/b-flash-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.0/b-1.5.2/b-colvis-1.5.2/b-flash-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable({

    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]

        }}
    );
} );
</script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may well have tried some or all of these, but here are some thoughts which may help:

1. Make sure you're not using any configuration from the [legacy](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features) version of datatables.  You are using 1.10+ - so make sure that you use the correct v1.10 config.
2. Get it working without any Django tags first - just a standalone page.  Then integrate the tags in stages so that you check it still works.
3. You can start with [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap) - get this working first and then add in the correct options as you need them.
4. Make sure you take some time to read the documentation - the datatables documentation is really good, and spending a bit of time on reading and understanding it will save a lot of time in the long run.

Also, try declaring your css / js imports in the HTML .

To start - just remove all the options and use the defaults:

```
    $('#example').DataTable( {

    } );
```

Once it's working, then make sure you add the correct options one at a time.

Comment: Been trying to get the super basic datatable layout going with no bootstrap and not getting any luck there. This is the example result. https://i.imgur.com/h2SfunZ.png - I've cleared all code but the one the datatable example uses

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nf50j3cm/#&togetherjs=FjamrJizOe

Comment: working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/matthewhegarty/ukrbe659/) - in jsfiddle, add the js / css dependencies via the [left nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321365/39296).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
  // Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainTable').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
            'excel', 'pdf'
        ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far but atm not working. Posted a JSFiddle above